# SQL Command: Exclude data that summarize to 0 in another table

Tags: sql

I have two source tables with a common reference number, called RECID in Source1 and TRANSRECID in Source2.
In Source1 there is an AMOUNT for each RECID.
In Source2 there is a SETTLEAMOUNT for each TRANSRECID.

```
select RECID AS Reference, SUM (AMOUNT) AS Amount
from Source1
GROUP BY RECID

select TRANSRECID AS Reference, SUM (SETTLEAMOUNT) AS Amount
from Source2
GROUP BY TRANSRECID
```

These two commands provides two tables with Reference and Amount.

I want to extract the lines from Source1 where AMOUNT for RECID = SETTLEAMOUNT for TRANSRECID (or AMOUNT - SETTLEAMOUNT = 0 when RECID = TRANSRECID) is excluded.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join`.  In Standard SQL:

```
select coalesce(a.reference, sa.reference), a.amount,
       sa.settleamount,
       coalesce(a.amount, 0) - coalesce(sa.settlementamount, 0) as diff
from (select RECID AS Reference, SUM(AMOUNT) AS Amount
      from Source1
      group by RECID
     ) a full join
     (select TRANSRECID AS Reference, SUM(SETTLEAMOUNT) AS SettleAmount
      from Source2
      group by TRANSRECID
     ) sa
     using (reference)
where coalesce(a.amount, 0) - coalesce(sa.settlementamount, 0);
```

You can also solve this problem by using `union all` and then aggregating:

```
select ss.reference, sum(ss.amount), sum(ss.settleamount),
       sum(ss.amount) - sum(ss.settlementamount) as diff
from ((select RECID AS Reference, amount, 0 as settleamount
       from Source1
       ) union all
       (select TRANSRECID AS Reference, 0, SettleAmount
        from Source2
       )
      ) ss
group by reference
having sum(amount) <> sum(sa.amount);
```

Comment: I get an error message that there is an incorrect syntax near Using.
Is there a problem when the table with RECID has more lines than the table with TRANSRECID?

Comment: @Attp30998 . . . You can use the second version.

Comment: I have managed to produced the table with the RECIDs that exist in SOURCE2, but doesn't summarize to 0 with AMOUNT and SETTLEAMOUNT.
I now have a problem with producing alle lines from SOURCE1 with the term WHERE RECID NOT IN (command used to produce table)

Comment: @Attp30998 . . . The second version has records from both tables.  Use that.